# XML Can't get value of child node : c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm newbie in XML ^_^

```
<a>
<book>
  <c>
       <e>Val1</e>
  </c>
  <d>val2</d>
</book>
<book>
  <c>
       <e>Val3</e>
  </c>
  <d>val4</d>
</book>
```

Question is i need to get value inside each book
first i use

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/a/book");
```

problem is node "c" has child "e" so i cant get its value like i get directly from node "d"

```
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                string Name = xn["e"].InnerText;   // Can't get its value
                string Detail = xn["d"].InnerText;
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: probably you should use FirstChild property

Comment: It's not obvious what you're trying to do... do you not know about the "c" element? Why aren't you going through that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select subnodes below the `<book>` node:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/a/book");

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    XmlNode eNode = xn.SelectSingleNode("c/e");

    if(eNode != null)
    {
         string Name = eNode.InnerText;
    }
}
```